# July/August vacation in Southeast Asia: any area not is dry and not affected by typhoon?

Tags: southeast-asia, beaches

I want to take a July/August vacation this year at a beach somewhere in Southeast Asia ( except Malaysia or Singapore, for I am all too familiar with those places).

I was planning to go to [Boracay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boracay), until I [learnt that during this season](https://altavistadeboracay.com.ph/blog/best-time-go-boracay):

> skies are cloudy, the air gives off a cool breeze, and rain showers
>   are more common. This is also the typhoon season in the Philippines.

Is there any other substitute in Southeast Asia?

Comment: Why the downvote ? Isn't this a perfectly valid and interesting question ?

Comment: It's not what you asked, hence a comment, but I went to Shanghai in April. The weather was really nice, not too hot but still nice enough for swimming. Not scorching hot like in July/August.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

July and August are rainy season for SE Asia, except for Indonesia which lies on the other side of the equator.  And as you discovered it is typhoon season, though westerly located countries like Thailand and Myanmar are not usually impacted by typhoon (they tend to lose power as they cross SE Asia's land mass).  Beach holidays will be subject to occasional rains most everywhere in SE Asia.